# Warning: require_once(Core.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\workspace\ecommerce\inc\autoload.php on line 9

Tags: php

Am Currently Following a e-commerce tutorial using php ... I get an warning when i run the file

index.php

```
<?php

require_once('inc/autoload.php');

$core = new Core();
```

autoload.php

```
<?php
require_once'config.php';

 function __autoload($class_name){

     $class = explode("_",$class_name);
     $path=implode("/",$class).".php";

     require_once($path);

 }
```

config.php

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION)){

    session_start();
}

defined("SITE_URL") ||
    define("SITE_URL","http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);


defined("DS") ||
  define("DS",DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined("ROOT_PATH") ||
    define("ROOT_PATH",realpath(dirname(__FILE__).DS."..".DS));

defined("CLASSES_DIR") ||
 define("CLASSES_DIR","classes");

defined("PAGES_DIR") ||
define("PAGES_DIR","pages");

defined("MOD_DIR") ||
define("MOD_DIR","mod");


defined("INC_DIR") ||
    define("INC_DIR","inc");



defined("TEMPLATE_DIR") ||
define("TEMPLATE_DIR","template");


defined("EMAILS_PATH") ||
define("EMAILS_PATH",ROOT_PATH.DS."emails");


defined("CATALOGUE_PATH") ||
define("CATALOGUE_PATH",ROOT_PATH.DS."media".DS."catalogue");


set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,array(

    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.CLASSES_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.CLASSES_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.PAGES_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.MOD_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.INC_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_PATH.DS.TEMPLATE_DIR),
    get_include_path()

)));
```

core.php

```
<?php

class Core{


    public function run (){

        echo 'fine till here';
    }
}
```

when i run the file i get a warning require_once(Core.php): failed to open stream ... can someone help me to figure out where have i made the mistake and thanks in  advance

Comment: Your autoloader obviously does not work properly. You should be using full paths to the files.

Comment: Yea but can u tell me what code should i exactly use

Comment: If your paths are definitely correct, it may be an issue of case sensitivity in Linux. i.e. because the first letter of the class is capitalised, you're trying to load `Core.php` when the actual file name is `core.php`. I tested your code in Windows and it worked for me without issue - after adding `$core->run();` to the end of `index.php` the output was the expected echo of `fine till here`.

Comment: hello @fridge_light my file name Core.php and even am using windows but it's not working for me !!!

Answer (score 1):

Use require_once('../inc/autoload.php')
Or save all the php files in your working dir like in case you are using wamp then save it in www. Then the syntax will be
require_once('autoload.php')